# Executing VxWorks 653 Applications With Shell Command

Tags: rtos, vxworks

I have simple execution problem with VxWorks 653 platform centerOS(windSh). In this shell i list current application with pdShow and also I want to run application on it but ı do not know the command and dont found command anywhere even the manual.

the Syntax of RTOS like this

```
[centerOS]-> pdShow
```

listing application on it

```
NAME         ID        TYPE     START ADRS    SIZE    L PRI H PRI TASK CNT
------------ ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- --------
centerOS         0x573818 KERNEL               0  0x9400000   255     0       35
partOS           0x839290 SYSTEM LIB  0x10000000    0xb4000     0     0        0
App              0x889010 APPLICATION 0x40000000  0x1000000   255   100        1
```

At that point i would like to execute App application but dont found the command and how to do it.
Any little help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to start the Application and this would depend on the configuration on your system.

As simple option would be to add the call to the startup of your application inside the partition and make sure that your partition is scheduled in the corresponding time window definition in the XML file.

From the Host Shell (WindSh) that would requires some setting in order to let you call the function in the context of that partition.
You can check if you can enter ":App" on the Shell (where you entered pdShow())